# GWT suggestBox performance issue

Tags: gwt, suggestbox

I have a suggestBox with a multiwordsuggestoracle. everything is working fine but there is a performance issue. I have to add around some 12000 Strings to the oracle, but adding this list takes a lot of time, which delays loading of the page. Once the page is loaded it works alright. I am doing just basic things, and i have searched and no one is getting such issue. So is there something i am missing, or is there some other way to remove this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try deferred loading of this. This will help you the page to load fast and later on you can load the string when needed.
The other choice isy create the whole HTML on server side and then attach it the DOM.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit on your second option ?